# How can I remove all annotations on my MkMapView that are not currently visible on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview

have a few annotations visible on my MkMapView using Swift 1.2 on iOS 8. Now if the user scrolls around the map, I'd like to remove all annotations, that are currently not visible.

How can I dow this?

Comment: Have you read my question? I know how to delete annotations. I want to know how to delete annotations that are currently NOT visible..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the currently visible mapRect:

```
let visRect = mapView.visibleMapRect
```

now you can get all annotations within that rect:

```
let inRectAnnotations = mapView.annotationsInMapRect(visRect)
```

last step would be to iterate over all annotations and check if you annotation is in these annotations

```
for anno : MKAnnotation in mapView.annotations {
  if (inRectAnnotations.contains(anno)) {
    //do what you want to do with the annotation (hide/remove)
  }
}
```